# How to handle "ValueError: array is too big." in Gensim when run LDA?

Tags: python, lda, gensim

I do as the gensim tutorial to run LAD on 195145 documents, 6636308 features, 188901082 non-zero entries.
The code is simple:

```
from gensim import corpora, models, similarities
class MyCorpus(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        for line in open('/home/pda/xxz149/LDA/DrugPatents.csv'):
            # assume there's one document per line, tokens separated by ','
            yield dictionary.doc2bow(line.lower().split(','))
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary.load('/home/pda/xxz149/LDA/DrugPatent.dict')
corpus = MyCorpus()
lda = models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus, num_topics = 300,id2word=dictionary,distributed = False,chunksize = 15, passes = 1 )
lda.save('/home/pda/xxz149/LDA/lda_DrugPatent.model')
```

But I meet the value error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gensim-0.10.0rc1-py2.6.egg/gensim/models/ldamodel.py", line 79, in __init__

    self.sstats = numpy.zeros(shape)
ValueError: array is too big.
```

The gensim is memory-friendly, Why this happen? How can I get through?

Comment: Are you on a 32bit system? What does `uname -a` say?

Comment: For me it says, Darwin local 16.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.0.0: Mon Aug 29 17:56:20 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3789.1.32~3/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 @Radim